Right side parking and tail lights + dash indicator + lights buzzer not working
On my 2nd gen. 2002 Toyota Previa/Estima/Tarago (ACR30), a weird issue occurred: at the same time, these four lights-related items stopped working:

parking light (RH)
tail light (RH)
parking lights dash indicator
door open lights warning buzzer

I replaced both rear and front bulbs but no change.
I have yet to check fuse (if I am able to locate the proper one). I am however intrigued by the fact that both the dash indicator and buzzer ceased to work while the left side parking and tail lights are still OK.
Question: Could a broken dash indicator indicator bulb cause such problem?
